# Communication between C++ DLL and a C# GUI

Tags: c#, c++, user-interface, dll, mfc

I am developing a Windows desktop application. The major functions of the application are executed in MFC c++ dll and the GUI is developed in c# WPF. The system runs as a TCP server and accepts clients to communicate with each other. This server-client communication must be handled in c++ dll. I want to notify c# GUI whenever a message is received from client. How can i maintain this communication from dll to GUI.

Comment: Why are the major functions executed in a C++ DLL, or why is the GUI written in C#? Doesn't having a GUI written in a separate language add a whole lot of unnecessary complexity?

Comment: I don't remember off the top of my head if MFC c++ is managed c++. You'll have to do some research on communicating between c# and managed c++. The way I've done it in the past is having the c# code register for a callback in the managed c++ code. Then when the managed c++ code receives a message, it passes the data to whoever registered for the callback (in this case a c# class).

Comment: @Dan -- MFC is unmanaged code.  @OP --Forget C# for the moment -- what if you had a C++ application that wanted the same notification from the DLL?  What would you do in that case?  Would you register some sort of callback?  If so, then see how the API functions such as `EnumWindows` works if you have a C# application.

Comment: How are you exposing the MFC capabilities. MFC has the facility to expose C++ classes to MFC applications, but you will not be able to consume them from C#. The easiest way to do this is to expose the capability via a straight C API, preferably one designed to be easily consumed by P/Invoke (and then consume it using P/Invoke). The other way is to expose expose your MFC DLL as a COM interface. While doing this, you'll need to remember to properly manage you MFC state.

Comment: I just re-read your question. To make your C# application callable fron unmanaged code, you'll need to expose one (or more) COM-callable interfaces. After three reads of your question, I still can't get the architecture clear in my head. Is this a single application (with the C# app hosting the MFC DLL), or is it two, a C# GUI app and an MFC app that calls into it. Or, is something else. You probably want to get a copy of Adam Nathan's ".NET and COM" book. It's the bible for these kinds of questions

Comment: @Flydog57 this is a single application. from c# using P/invoke i can call functions from dll and get the return data, but in this case i want the dll to be able to send data to GUI whenever it receives any client message.

Comment: Pass a COM callable interface down. It's been a very long time since I knew any of this, but there may also be a way to send a callback down to the unmanaged code, that's implemented as a delegate on the C# side. Whenever I've done anything like this, I've pulled out the Adam Nathab book

Comment: The most direct way to communicate between managed and unmanaged code is to use [C++/CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/dotnet-programming-with-cpp-cli-visual-cpp). Particularly, [Native and .NET Interoperability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/native-and-dotnet-interoperability) provides a high-level overview of how this can be done. COM interop is also possible, as mentioned above. Not as direct, and with the added requirement to be familiar with COM.